# Labyrinth console game - Two dimensional Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I want to create a mini game in console something like labyrinth. 
I need to create something like this at first
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3SZS.jpg
My question is, how can i fill array like a gamemap without defining every single one [][] position as i already did

```
   `char s = '#';
    char [][] ary = new char [5][5];x
    ary[0][0] = s;
    ary[0][1] = s;
    ary[0][2] = s;
    ary[0][4] = s;

    ary[1][0] = s;
    ary[1][1] = s;
    ary[1][4] = s;

    ary[2][0] = s;
    ary[2][1] = s;
    ary[2][3] = s;
    ary[2][4] = s;

    ary [3][0] = s;
    ary [3][3] = s;
    ary [3][4] = s;

    ary [4][2] = s;
    ary [4][3] = s;
    ary [4][4] = s;
```

I want to make it simpler something like

```
char [][] ary {{#, #, #, , #};
               {#, #, , , #};
```

and so on..

It is possible?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The map data should be stored as data, not as code, probably in this case as a text file, perhaps something that looks like:

```
# # # # # # #
#   #   #   #
#   #       #
#         # #
# # # # # # #
```

You should then have code that reads in the text file and uses its information to fill your map array. I would use a Scanner object initialized with the text file, and then read in each line with its own separate Scanner initialized with each line of text, and fill my array in nested for loops.

By placing the labyrinth in the data domain, you greatly increase the flexibility of your program, now allowing you to change your map **without changing your code**.

Something like this could work if you knew with certainty the text file's contents including the number of lines and the number tokens per line...

```
public static char[][] readMap(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException {
  char[][] map = new char[MAP_ROWS][MAP_COLUMNS];
  File mapFile = new File(filePath);
  Scanner mapScanner = new Scanner(mapFile);
  for (int row = 0; row < map.length; row++) {
     String line = mapScanner.nextLine();
     Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
     for (int col = 0; col < map[row].length; col++) {
        map[row][col] = lineScanner.next().charAt(0);
     }
     lineScanner.close();
  }
  if (mapScanner != null) {
     mapScanner.close();
  }

  return map;
}
```

Otherwise consider using nested ArrayLists and checking availability of Scanner tokens before reading.